# SSIS Dynamic XML Configuration Path

Tags: xml, path, ssis, config

Folks,

My package has all the user variables specified in the XMl config that will be located in one of the package's folders.

The thing is the config file's path itself is hardcoded in the package...

When moving the entire folder structure to the PROD environment I will be able to reconfigure the user variable paths accorodingly in the XML config file ...but what about the location of the XML config file itself?

How do I manage this path?

Any info appreciated.

Comment: What version of SSIS? As long as you have a different server for each environment, use the method that Kosh has suggested.

Comment: I am using the 2005 version. 
I am not fast on setting the environment variable for it...

Thanks anyway.

Comment: The other option is using the deployment wizard, but The environment variable method is a far simpler step than using the deployment wizard. The deployment wizard is a manual unscripted step which changes your SSIS source code, and needs to manually stepped through by a person every time you migrate. The environment variable is done ONCE on every server and then no manual migration steps are required  afterwards (provided you make use of it in your package) - you just copy your package (without requiring a wizard or manual intervention) and it works.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the Configuration Type, select the second option to store the configuration location in an environment variable.  To change the XML location go to Start > Computer and right click on Computer.  Select System Properties and then the Advanced tab.  At the bottom you'll see a button for Environment Variables.  Select it and then search through the System list for the variable to which you assigned the XML location.  Here the XML location can be changed.

When the package goes to production, all you need to do is create the Environment Variable there and define the new location under System Properties.  There is no need to modify the SSIS package.

Hope this helps.

Kosh

Comment: Kosh, thanks. I'm well aware of the option you mentioned; however, it means yet another deployment step for our infrastructure team.
Since this need tested on several envoronments they all will need a new environmental variable created and this could be potentially overlooked causing the SSIS to fail. 

Is this the only way of setting this path?